# Is this example of diagonalizable matrix in error?

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

I am reading through Axler *Linear Algebra Done Right* and come across this example.

Define $T\in\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ by
$$T(x,y)=(41x+7y,-20x+74y).$$

The matrix of $T$ with respect to the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is
$$\begin{pmatrix}41&7\\-20&74\end{pmatrix},$$
which is not a diagonal matrix.  However, $T$ is diagonalizable, because the matrix of $T$ with respect to the basis $(1,4),(7,5)$ is
$$\begin{pmatrix}69&0\\0&46\end{pmatrix},$$
as you should verify.

Well, I am *trying* to verify it, but I keep getting the matrix of $T$ with respect to that latter basis as
$$\begin{pmatrix}69&322\\276&230\end{pmatrix}.$$

Am I doing something wrong, or is the book in error?  More generally, how can I find a diagonalization of a matrix whenever I want to?

Comment: What did you try to reach $\left(\begin{array}{}69&322\\276&230\end{array}\right)$?

Comment: Calculated $T(1,4)=(41(1)+7(4),-20(1)+74(4))=(69,276)$ and $T(7,5)=(41(7)+7(5),-20(7)+74(5))=(322,230)$.  This is how I have always calculated a matrix of $T$ with respect to bases of $V$.

Comment: This is not the definition of the matrix of $T$ with respect to a basis of $V$. See my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of putting to coefficients of $T(1,4)$ with respect to the basis $\mathcal{B} = ((1,4),(7,5))$ in the first column of your matrix, you have put $T(1,4)$ directly (or more precisely the coefficients of $T(1,4)$ with respect to the standard basis $((1,0),(0,1))$). You have

$$ T(1,4) = (41 + 28, -20 + 296) = (69, 276) = 69 \cdot (1,4) + 0 \cdot (7,5) $$

so the first column of $[T]_{\mathcal{B}}$ is $(69, 0)^t$ and not $(69, 276)^t$.

Comment: Aha.  Thank you for that correction.  I see my mistake clearly now.